# Multiple aggregations on one column in a Pandas dataframe to return two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with the following data:

```
df:
eventid, locationid, eventname, eventdate, attended, earlyarrival, exitpolled, pollscomplete, timeframe
1, 12, Event X, 2018-03-14 07:00:00, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2018
2, 14, Event Y, 2017-07-03 07:00:00, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2017
3, 14, Event Z, 2017-07-05 07:00:00, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2017
...
```

I am attempting to run the following on it to aggregate it:

```
finaloutput = df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df.eventdate).dt.strftime('%m/%Y'), 'locationid']).agg({'eventid': 'nunique', 'attended':lambda x: (x==1).sum(), 'earlyarrival':lambda x: (x==1).sum(), 'exitpolled':lambda x: (x==1).sum(), 'pollscomplete':lambda x: (x==1).sum(), 'pollscomplete':lambda x: x.eq(1).sum()})
```

The problem I am having is I am not getting two columns back for the lambda functions on pollscomplete.  I am looking to add in both the number of polls complete along with just a case of how many events had completed polls in my final dataset to be pivoted.  I am guessing when aggregating it is not possible to apply two lambda functions to return two distinct columns back into the dataframe without mapping it and defining a new column.  Is this correct?

Current Result:

```
eventdate, locationid, eventid, attended, earlyarrival, exitpolled, pollscomplete
2017-07-01, 14, 2, 1, 1, 1
2018-03-14, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1
```

Expected Result:

```
eventdate, locationid, eventid, attended, earlyarrival, exitpolled, pollscomplete, pollscomplete
2017-07-01, 14, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3
2018-03-14, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3
```

As demonstrated above, I want both a count and sum for pollscomplete.

Comment: I don't completely understand your `groupby`, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Another thing, can columns `earlyarrival` and `exitpolled` (`attended`?) only contain `0` or `1`?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind - sorry for the question, I got this working by nesting both of the lambda functions into a list.  The following is the code - please let me know if there is a better way to do this:

```
finaloutput = (df.groupby([pd.to_datetime(df.eventdate).dt.strftime('%m/%Y'), 'locationid'])
                  .agg({'eventid': 'nunique', 
                        'attended': lambda x: (x==1).sum(), 
                        'earlyarrival': lambda x: (x==1).sum(), 
                        'exitpolled': lambda x: (x==1).sum(), 
                        'pollscomplete': [lambda x: (x==1).sum(), lambda x: x.eq(1).sum()]
                       }))
```

The only weird thing about this is now all of my columns have been renamed to "lambda" despite the operation used.

Comment: `lambda x: (x==1).sum(), lambda x: x.eq(1).sum()` and I wonder what the difference is.

Comment: One should count where=1, the other should sum all the values counted.

Comment: As far as I can tell, they give the exact same result. Can you see they are different somewhere?

Comment: Good catch - I tested it and fixed.